# How can I get my turtle to stop moving, and end the event

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I'm making a "game" where the turtle has to stay in the square, and if it moves out the game ends. I used the break command in a while loop, and in the instructional video provided with the assessment, it worked, but I can't get it too.If you're confused, I want the turtle to be unable to move when it goes out of the square. What can I do? Here is the code

```
import turtle
import random

turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt.speed("100")
tart = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

def up():
  turt.setheading(90)
  turt.forward(10)
def down():
  turt.setheading(270)
  turt.forward(10)
def left():
  turt.setheading(180)
  turt.forward(10)
def right():
  turt.setheading(0)
  turt.forward(10)
  
screen.onkey(up, "w")
screen.onkey(down, "s")
screen.onkey(left, "a")
screen.onkey(right, "d")
screen.listen()

tart.speed("100101001010000010101010000010010100")
tart.shape("square")
tart.penup()
tart.goto(-250,250)
tart.pendown()
for i in range(4):
  tart.forward(400)
  tart.right(90)
tart.forward(100)
tart.penup()
tart.goto(-2000000000,200000000000000000000)


  
while True:
  
  r = random.randint(0,255)
  g = random.randint(0,255)
  b = random.randint(0,255)
  turt.color(r,g,b)
  
  if turt.ycor() > 250 or turt.xcor() > -250:
    break
  
  elif turt.xcor() > 250 or turt.ycor() < -250:
    break

  

#----------------------------------
tart.speed("100101001010000010101010000010010100")
tart.shape("square")
tart.penup()
tart.goto(-400,300)
tart.pendown()
```

Comment: You can remove the keyboard hooks: `screen.onkey(None, "w")`, etc.

Comment: There are other errors. `turt.speed("100")` That function expects a number: `turt.speed(100)` And `if turt.ycor() > 250 or turt.xcor() > -250:` should be `if turt.ycor() > 250 or turt.xcor() < -250:`

Comment: Do you have a link to the instructional video?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, the turtle `speed()` method can take a string (`'slow'`, `'fastest'`, etc.) or a number (0 - 10) though the arguments the OP provided aren't valid for either.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has a number of mistakes and inconsistencies.  Let's take it apart and put it back together as a proper turtle program.  (No `while True:` needed nor desired.)

```
from turtle import Pen, Turtle, Screen

def up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    if turtle.ycor() < 240:
        turtle.forward(10)

def down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    if -240 < turtle.ycor():
        turtle.forward(10)

def left():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    if -240 < turtle.xcor():
        turtle.forward(10)

def right():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    if turtle.xcor() < 240:
        turtle.forward(10)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

pen = Pen()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-250, 250)
pen.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    pen.forward(500)
    pen.right(90)

screen = Screen()

screen.onkey(up, 'w')
screen.onkey(down, 's')
screen.onkey(left, 'a')
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

I removed your questionable turtle color logic for simplicity as it had no bearing on your quesion.